# how to sum data from json object ? flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am building shopping and I am new to flutter I am calling data from my server by the below method:

```
 Future getCartData() async {
 print("this is the token mytoken");
 String url = 'https://myurl.com/apis/getCartItems';
 http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "token mytoken",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: json.encode({
      "username": "admin",
    }));
 print(response.body);
 var data = json.decode(response.body);
 print("cart data recieved :");
 print(data.length);
 return data;
```

}

and my JSON data looks like this:

```
{  {
   "id":"8",
   "title":"art-fusion gold",
   "itemimage":"/media/10.jpg",
   "price":3499.0
    },
    {
   "id":"9",
   "title":"ruby gold",
   "itemimage":"/media/11.jpg",
   "price":3699.0
   }
 }
```

and I am accessing every item detail in future builder as:

> list[index]['title']

everything working great I just want to add prices and store them into a variable so that I can show my users what there total price is but I don't know how to add this "price" variable from JSON.

can someone please help thanks in advance <3

Comment: The json data is not an array format so you can't get the length of this json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var totalPrice = 0;
```

and then in your loop

```
totalPrice = totalPrice + list[index]['price'];
```

Then print or use this totalPrice variable.

But it is not a good way to access json data. Try to make data model/pojo class and then by using model/pojo class access data.

Comment: it worked !! and thanks for your suggestion i will consider it in my future projects <3